# How to Show ImageView trimmed so that the height is equal to the width?

Tags: android, imageview

I need to make an Android Application that displays a square image. But receives images of a width greater than high. But you need to show square.

This is what I have.

[image]

This is what I need

[image]

Comment: add scaleType=fitXY to your imageview in xml

Comment: `android:scaleType="fitXY"` no work.

Comment: `<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenPromoImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>`

Comment: you problem then must be with weight. You must be giving less weight to imageview then the space available. Also you should keep the parameter as 0 dp for which you are adding weight i.e if weight is for height then height should be 0dp and vice versa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use these two parameters in `ImageView` in xml:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this in xml file

```
<ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: This may change the aspect ratio of the src.

Answer (score 0):

where view2 is ur imageview. create a method scaleimage and call it in Oncreate(). like this - scaleImage(view2, 160); // in dp

```
private void scaleImage(ImageView view, int xboundBoxInDp)
    {
        // Get the ImageView and its bitmap
        Drawable drawing = view.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();

        // Get current dimensions
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();

        // Determine how much to scale: the dimension requiring less scaling is
        // closer to the its side. This way the image always stays inside your
        // bounding box AND either x/y axis touches it.
        float xScale = ((float) xboundBoxInDp) / width;
        float yScale = ((float) xboundBoxInDp) / height;
        float scale = (xScale >= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

        // Create a matrix for the scaling and add the scaling data
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

        // Create a new bitmap and convert it to a format understood by the ImageView
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
        BitmapDrawable result = new BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap);
        width = scaledBitmap.getWidth();
        height = scaledBitmap.getHeight();

        // Apply the scaled bitmap
        view.setImageDrawable(result);

        // Now change ImageView's dimensions to match the scaled image
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private int dpToPx(int dp)
    {
        float density = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return Math.round((float) dp * density);
    }
```